# renaming multiple columns of vectors in data frame without typing all names

Tags: r

Instead of typing c("Col1","Col2","Col3", "Col4", "Col5", "Col6", "Col7", "Col8", "Col9", "Col10"), can I use something easier for instance c(Col[1:10])

```
library("plyr")
df<-as.data.frame(matrix)
colnames(df) <- c("Col1","Col2","Col3", "Col4", "Col5", "Col6", "Col7", "Col8", "Col9", "Col10")
rownames(df) <- rownames(hypo100.1.df, do.NULL = FALSE, prefix = "Obs.")
df$Col1 <- as.factor(df$Col1)               
df$Col2 <- as.character(df$Col2)             
df$Col3 <- as.numeric(df$Col3)               
df
```

Comment: Use `paste0("Col", 1:10)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To demonstrate [MrFlick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64073228/renaming-multiple-columns-of-vectors-in-data-frame-without-typing-all-names#comment113303342_64073228)'s solution in action.

```r
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(1:20, ncol = 10))

# Without column names
df
#>   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10
#> 1  1  3  5  7  9 11 13 15 17  19
#> 2  2  4  6  8 10 12 14 16 18  20

# Add column names quickly
colnames(df) <- paste0("Col", 1:10)

# With column names
df
#>   Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 Col5 Col6 Col7 Col8 Col9 Col10
#> 1    1    3    5    7    9   11   13   15   17    19
#> 2    2    4    6    8   10   12   14   16   18    20
```

<sup>Created on 2020-09-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>